# using dynamic sql safely

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-injection

When testing the following code I keep getting no results. But my architect is telling me that I need to write it as such to avoid all SQL injection attacks. I cant see what I am missing. Tried originally getting the type of the column then using that in the ParameterDefinition field.

Basically what I do is get a database, then return all the columns. Then the use will create a condition, at that point i go to the database and run my query against that specific table with the filer they specified. Now after checking the DB it is not working. I am stressed and have invested more time than I can afford to into this Stored Procedure.

Please assist if you can!

Samantha

```
DECLARE @return_value int

EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[usp_Dev_GetSpecificTable]
        @TableName = N'tb_CountryCode',
        @RowsDesired = 10,
        @Operator = N'=',
        @Column = N'Name',
        @TextToFind = N'ANDORRA'

SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value

GO
```

Running this against my stored procedure below

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_Dev_GetSpecificTable]
    @TableName VARCHAR(100),
    @RowsDesired INT,
    @Operator VARCHAR(100),
    @Column VARCHAR(100),
    @TextToFind VARCHAR(100)
AS 
BEGIN
    DECLARE @sql AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
    DECLARE @type AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
    DECLARE @ParameterDefinition AS NVARCHAR(100)
    SET @type = 'SELECT TOP(1) DATA_TYPE FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME =  ' + QUOTENAME(@TableName) + ' AND COLUMN_NAME = ' + @Column 
    SET @sql = 'SELECT * FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@TableName) + ' WHERE ' + @Column +' = '+'''+@TextToFind+'''
    SET @ParameterDefinition =  '@TextToFind varchar'
    EXECUTE sp_executesql @sql
END
```

Comment: Yeah that is wide open to sql injection attack. Why do you need a generic stored procedure to return the rows of any table? This is like making a method in .net that will return any object. That being said, you need to parameterize your dynamic sql. Look at your where clause. What would happen if somebody passed in '1=1; delete SomeTable;--' as the Column? This type of procedure is very difficult to lock down because it a type of "one procedure to rule them all". The performance of this is likely to really stink too because you have to implicitly cast every datatype to a varchar.

Comment: Maybe this line: `SET @sql = 'SELECT * FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@TableName) + ' WHERE ' + @Column +' = '+'''+@TextToFind+'''` looks vulnerable, if @TextToFind is something like = "'my text'; DROP TABLE Users;"

Comment: The account type that I am using to reach the database is read only for this case. The reason we need such a result is that the production database is now outside developments grasp. So they want me to be able to create a view where they can select a database, then a column to filter on, and return that set of records up to the top 2000 records.

Comment: This is not sufficient to prevent sql injection. Also if you want the top 2000 rows shouldn't you have a TOP AND an order by? This whole thing screams of being a short term fix with long term issues.

Comment: they want a short term fix now, and then investigate into what they need. But currently we have access to the production environments, like errorlogs. thats primarily the reason for this. to let us still see the database from a troubleshooting perspective

Comment: short term fixes = headaches later, fix it the first time the right way and you will save money in the long run.

Comment: Use QUOTENAME() around Column for starters.  And you probably want to replace TextToFind with something like REPLACE(TextToFind, '''', '''''') just to escape any single quotes that might be in that string (to help ward off SQL injection attack from that angle).